# AWS CDK CLI: Passing environment variables when running cdk deploy command

Tags: go, environment-variables, aws-cdk

I have written some infrastructure code with AWS CDK (Go). My code is structured like so:

```
.
├── api
│   └── aj
│       ├── lambda
│       │   └── main.go
│       ├── email.go
│       ├── emailService.go
│       ├── handler.go
│       └── handler_test.go
├── cdk
│   ├── cdk.go
│   ├── cdk.json
│   ├── cdk_test.go
│   └── README.md
├── 00-test-image.jpg
├── go.mod
└── go.sum

5 directories, 12 files
```

My CDK code simply creates an AWS Lambda HTTP Endpoint that will handle a form submission and send an email.

I am using the [algnhsa Go adapter package](https://github.com/akrylysov/algnhsa) to make things easier to deploy.

At the top of my `emailService.go` I have the following:

```
var (
    host       = os.Getenv("EMAIL_HOST")
    username   = os.Getenv("EMAIL_USERNAME")
    password   = os.Getenv("EMAIL_PASSWORD")
    portNumber = os.Getenv("EMAIL_PORT")
)
```

My question is, when I run `cdk deploy`, how do I set those environment variables so that they're available and set within the code?

Answer (score 0):

You configure the Lambda Function's environment variables with its [Environment](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/aws/aws-cdk-go/awscdk/v2/awslambda#FunctionProps) prop as a `*map[string]*string`.

You'd typically pass the values down as stack props from its parent stack to the Lambda construct.  Or simply hardcode the values in the Function construct code.  The CDK best practice is to have such input values [fixed at synth-time](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/best-practices.html#best-practices-apps), so that deploys are deterministic and under source control.